# JavaScript nonresponsive when editing document draft

Tags: bug, documentation

While editing https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/504/objects-classes?draftId=24215 the page became gradually nonresponsive and eventually resulted in a crashed tab in Chrome. In Firefox I am able to edit, but get constant Unresponsive Script tags. I've reproduced this issue after closing and reopening Firefox with empty tabs. Chrome hangs up loading the page and eventually crashes the tab.

Firefox 47.0 / Chrome 51.0.2704.103 (64-bit) / OS X 10.10.5

Note: It seems to be a problem with Markdown preview rendering. If I kill the offending script, I get the browser back, but the entire section I'm editing appears blank in the editor window.

[image: Error while editing]